# Meteor Html pages appearing in single window

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to use iron router to route the html pages on click events.But as I run the application, all pages appear in the main page itself, whereas the click event doesn't route the page needed.The JS code as below

```
    Template.Login.events({
    'submit form': function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $('[name=userId]').val();
    var password = $('[name=password]').val();
    if(username == '' && password ==''){
        alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    }
    else if( username =='deal' && password ==''){
        alert("You are logged in as a Deal manager");
        Meteor.Router.to("/dashboard");

    }
    else if( username =='practice' && password ==''){
        alert("You are logged in as a Practice manager");
        Meteor.Router.to("/pracDashboard");
    }
    }  
    });
```

As in the above is a login page with conditions as 'deal' or 'practice' to route to different pages.The moment I place the dashboard.html in the folder, both the login and dashboard page appear in the same window.

Comment: There is no change.Still both login.html and dashboard.html appears in the same page window.On submit with username=deal the page refreshes and  remains the same.Also as I have added the Iron:Router to the project, the Iron Router splash also comes in the html.Need help as I am not finding a way to clear this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying a page we should convert the html page in template form. Let say login.html is as follows

```
<html>
    <title>Sample title</title>
    <body>Sample Text</body>
</html>
```

for meteor the html page should be like this

```
<template name="login">
     Sample Text
</template>
```

Then for displaying login page we need to implement Route like this

```
Router.route('/login', function (){
    this.render('login.html');
});
```

So set Router first then in events during submit redirect.

```
Router.route('/dashboard', function (){
    this.render('dashboard.html');
});

Router.route('/pracDashboard', function (){
    this.render('pracDashboard.html');
});

Router.route('/login', function (){
    this.render('login.html');
});

Template.login.events({
    'submit form': function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $('[name=userId]').val();
        var password = $('[name=password]').val();
        if(username == '' && password =='') {
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        } else if( username =='deal' && password =='') {
            alert("You are logged in as a Deal manager");
            Router.go("/dashboard");
        } else if( username =='practice' && password ==''){
            alert("You are logged in as a Practice manager");
            Router.go("/pracDashboard");
        }
    }  
});
```